# display progress while doing multiple db inserts in php/mysql codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, hook, codeigniter-2

**php**

```
    foreach($this->input->post('dx') as $dx){  
        $r=$this->general->insert_record('prescriptions',$dx);
    }
    foreach($this->input->post('mf') as $mf){               
       $r=$this->general->insert_record('visit_inputs',$mf);
    }
    $r=$this->general->update_record('visits',$array3);
```

on html page i use ajax to submit for to this php function.

my question is , how can i display $r[] back to user after each insertion ?

example of $r  after each insert

```
<ul><!--after first insert-->
<li>Dx inserted</li>
</ul>


<ul><!--after 2nd insert-->
<li>Dx inserted</li>
<li>mf inserted</li>
</ul>

<ul><!--after 3rdinsertion-->
<li>Dx inserted</li>
<li>mf inserted</li>
<li>record updated</li>
</ul>
```

do i have to split each insert into diffrent function and call it one after other via ajax? or is there a way to echo $r while in progress ?

Answer (score 0):

Trap the 'onreadystatechange' event and look for the 'readyState' = 4 with response = 200. Then read the value and put it in a div or some entity with a unique id. Have your server side code return the necc values.

More info: [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp).